# Animate images with fade effect in Collection view cells

Tags: ios, swift, image, animation, uicollectionview

Note: I have tried all matching questions from stack overflow but none helped to fix this issue/scenario hence posting.

I have a collection view in which i have number of cells where each cell has one image view. Each cell will have different array of images which i need to show one after another through fade effect. First time it shows correctly however when i scroll then problems arises. First cell's image/s displays in any other cell. Images shuffles.

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagesArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath)
//        let image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
//        let imgArr =  imagesArray[indexPath.row]
//        image.downloadImageAndAnimateIt(imageStringArray: imgArr)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = self.collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2 - 5
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size - 5)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        let imgArr =  imagesArray[indexPath.row]
        image.downloadImageAndAnimateIt(imageStringArray: imgArr)

    }


}
//=========== END of view controller

extension UIImageView {

    func downloadImageAndAnimateIt(imageStringArray:[String]){

        var imagesArray = [UIImage]()
        for imgStr in imageStringArray{
            imagesArray.append(UIImage(named: imgStr)!)
        }        

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
//        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {[weak self] in
//            self?.animationImages = imagesArray.compactMap({$0})
//            self?.animationDuration = 5.0
//            self?.startAnimating()
//        }

        var photoCount = 0        
        var timer = Timer()

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {[weak self] in

            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
                if (photoCount < imagesArray.count - 1){
                    photoCount = photoCount + 1;
                }else{
                    photoCount = 0;
                }
                if let this = self {
                    UIView.transition(with: this, duration: 2.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                        this.image = imagesArray[photoCount]
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
            })

        }

    }

}
```

Images should not shuffle and those should remain on the same cell as it was before scrolling.

Comment: set image.image = nil before downloading image

Comment: Hi Jaydeep, thanks for replying.
i have done a demo project where i have used images from assets and performing animation. Tried your solution but issue still exists.

Comment: can you upload demo   project to drop box and share link here

Comment: please find the link below for demo project
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yJjLLh3-WFuVnytfbxfVVvuJZ4VBRVzj

Comment: sorry for the late replay i think problem is in imageview extention
try the code i have answered below i have tested the code is not shuffling the image

Answer (score 2):

You have to create CustomCollectionCell class to seperate your code try using following way and also for download image you can use **SDWebImage**

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagesArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.imgView.image = nil
        cell.createImages(imageStringArray: imagesArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.configureTimer()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = self.collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2 - 5
        return CGSize(width: size, height: (size * 1.5) - 5)
    }



}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }
    var imageArray:[UIImage] = []
    var timer = Timer()
    var photoCount: Int = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    func createImages(imageStringArray:[String])
    {
        self.imageArray.removeAll()
        for imgStr in imageStringArray
        {
          self.imageArray.append(UIImage.init(named: imgStr) ?? UIImage.init())
        }

    }
    func configureTimer()
    {
        self.timer.invalidate()
        self.imgView.image = self.imageArray[self.photoCount] //Set Default Image First Time
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            if (self.photoCount < self.imageArray.count - 1){
                self.photoCount = self.photoCount + 1;
            }else{
                self.photoCount = 0;
            }
            if let imageView = self.imgView {
                UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 2.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    imageView.image = self.imageArray[self.photoCount]
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases you will need to handle while downloading an image and showing it inside `UITableView`/ `UICollectionView` cell:

1. Threading: Image should be assigned to `UIImageView` on main thread.
2. After download completes, check if cell is still visible and you are assigning it to correct index.

I will strongly recommend to use one of the libraries for this like **SDWebImage**

Comment: Here issue is not with dowloader as you can check in demo even assets are not loaded properly hence issue is with image extention

Answer (score 0):

What is actually happening here is collectionView is reusing previous cell so image from previous cell is loaded in new cell when image is under downloading to remove this behavior you need to set a placeholder image **Or** you may set image empty

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath)
        let image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
         image.image = "placeholderImage" // replace it with your place holder image 
//Or 
//     image.image = UIImage()
        let imgArr =  imagesArray[indexPath.row]
        image.downloadImageAndAnimateIt(imageStringArray: imgArr)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = self.collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2 - 5
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size - 5)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    }
```